# Safari Browser Issue: Fixed footer is hiding the bottom part of my content

Tags: html, css, grid, hidden

The following is a problem with the Safari browser. It works fine with Chrome. I am working on a grid based portfolio site that is having some problems with the content being hidden. The last three tiles of a 3 x 4 grid are being cut off currently, is there any way to make them visible when you scroll? Thanks!

Demo: www.mindtale.com/portfolio.html

portfolo.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"> 
<title>Mindtale Test Home</title>
</head>

<body>




<!-- Header -->

<div id="headerlogo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>

<div id="headerfill"></div>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="headerlink1">

<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>

<div id="headerlink2">
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>


<!-- Content -->


<div id="gridcontainer">

<div id="portfolio-grid">

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

</div>



<!-- <div id="content">
<h2>A random heading</h2>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>

</div> -->

<!-- Footer -->

<div id="footer">
Mindtale &copy; 2013
</div>

</body>
```

style.css

```
html { 
height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* add background image */
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-moz-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-o-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
}

/* Header */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */



div#header {
z-index:3;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center;
height: 102px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerfill {
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/headerfill.png) repeat-x;
height: 98px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink1 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:18%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink2 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:78%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlogo {
z-index:5;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:42%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

/* Content */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#content {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
color:#222;
top: 70px; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
padding: 25px;
overflow: auto;



font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}


/* Footer */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
color:#999;
background:#333;
padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: You're missing your `DOCTYPE` declaration.

Comment: You could look at them in a more forgiving browser.  :)  It works just as you ask in Chrome.

Comment: My point is that I didn't read your question closely enough.  I thought you said that you were seeing the *entire* last row cut off, which wasn't what I saw.  Assumed it was a browser difference. Sorry.

Comment: @Animatoring Did any of these answers help you? Let us know by an upvote or correct answer.

Comment: So far none of these have worked for Safari. They work in Chrome. It could 100% just be my user failure of them, I'm pretty new to coding beyond the absolute basics. I'll try again and see if either do anything.

I follow the logic of needing to add "blank content" so to speak to make the real content of the grid visible. I'm not sure why none of them are working.

Comment: I'll upvote one of the answers either way before the end of the day, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have a footer that has a CSS property of `position:fixed;`. This takes the footer out of the element flow, making the content that comes just before the footer hide behind the footer.

Try adding `padding-bottom:50px;` to `div#gridcontainer`, like so:

```
#gridcontainer {
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 996px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: and also he can make his footer a bit transparent.

Comment: @1337holiday "and also he can make his footer a bit transparent." That doesn't solve anything. It's just a different style.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok do you UNDERSTAND the concept of fixed positioning? a footer that is locked to the bottom will never move therefore any page that is longer than the current viewport will be hidden behind it. There is no way to fix this other than making compromises like opacity.....OR NOT locking the footer

Comment: Actually, @1337holiday, my solution works without either of your compromises my compromise is with semantics.

Comment: @Fillip, if you edit this (any edit will do) I will reverse my down-vote.

Comment: +1 for padding-bottom: 50px; in Chrome. It unfortunately doesn't work in Safari though, any ideas for a Safari fix?

Comment: Since this is now the accepted answer, I'd suggest that you'd edit your answer to reflect the cross-browser solution to help future SO users.

Answer (score 2):

Another, less semantic way to solve this (but the padding solution above is better):

The fixed footer has been removed from the DOM flow, so you have to add some space at the bottom of the div that precedes the footer so that what the footer is blocking doesn't matter.

You can create the padding you need by adding another element after your last portfolio-website div.

```
<div class="spacer">
</div>
```

and then give it some height, and clear it:

```
.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: While I agree this is another solution to the problem, some of your points are incorrect:

`The fixed footer has been removed from the dom...` - When an element has a fixed position, it is definitely not removed from the DOM. It is just moved in the flow of the markup.

`Adding margins and padding...won't help because there are no elements in the DOM flow with height beneath them.` - While this is true, it doesn't matter since all is needed is the bottom of the page.

Lastly, this solution is not very semantic. And my solution *does* fix this, but it sounds like you didn't test it yourself.

Comment: The W3 says "Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning.", and says the following about Absolute Positioning "It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings)." (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I rushed in my typing above and left out the word "flow" the first time I was writing about the DOM. (I'll fix that in a second).  And actually I thought I had attempted your solution, but apparently I messed up, because when I tried it again just now, I see that it works.

Comment: When I tried to do this in jsFiddle on Chrome it doesn't work. The element has a height of zero. I'd set the height to 50 and just remove the margin.

Answer (score 1):

The following works with overlapping content for a fixed footer in Safari:

```
#gridcontainer {
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 100px;
    position: overflow;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 996px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

For Safari you will need: position -> overflow, and give the content padding so it shows in the area of the screen needed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier, but glad you found a solution!

Comment: Actually, I'm curious how this works, as there is no `position:overflow;` css property. Maybe it was taking the place of a previous `position` property that was causing the issue?